# Visio 2007のThisDocument内のマクロが動かず落ちる。

Tags: visio

Private Sub Document_DocumentOpened(ByVal doc As IVDocument)が実行されずに落ちます。
上記プログラムを含むVisioファイルをVisio 2007で開くとVisioが落ちてしまいます。

環境はVisio 2013とVisio 2007の混在されているPCです。
Visio 2013を起動すると以下のような画面が表示され一旦デフォルトで開くVisioがVisio2013に切り替わります。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

次にVisio 2007を起動すると、上記ダイアログのVisio2007のものが表示されます。

ここまで行い、デフォルトのVisioが2007に戻ったところでVisioファイルを開こうとすると、Visioが開かなくなりました。
また、ThisDocument内のイベント以外は動作します。
たとえば、標準モジュール内にプロシージャを作成し、MsgBoxを表示させることはできます。

また、thisDocumentにイベントがなければVisioは2007で開くことができます。

いったんこうなるとVisioの再インストールでも治らなくなります。

何か、解決方法はないでしょうか。

Comment: “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\OFFICE12\VISIO.EXE” /regserver　を試しても効果はなかったです。

Comment: 自己解決しました。Visio 2007のSP3をインストールすることで解決しました。